# Question about 2010 Flash Crash

Tags: stocks

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_flash_crash):

> In April 2015, Navinder Singh Sarao, a London-based point-and-click
> trader,[63] was arrested for his alleged role in the flash crash.
> According to criminal charges brought by the United States Department
> of Justice, Sarao allegedly used an automated program to **generate
> large sell orders, pushing down prices,** which he then cancelled to buy
> at the lower market prices. The Commodity Futures Trading Commission
> filed civil charges against Sarao.

My question is: how can simply generating sell orders push down the price? For the "price" to move down, the sells have to actually get executed, to reflect the last traded price.

Comment: Elsewhere in the link it states that `The Commodity Futures Trading Commission (CFTC) investigation concluded that Sarao "was at least significantly responsible for the order imbalances" in the derivatives market which affected stock markets and exacerbated the flash crash.`  That suggests that he was part of the problem not the sole cause of the problem.